# Is there any way to prevent a line from wrapping around while in visual mode?

Tags: visual-mode, wrapping

If I am using visual block mode to append to a block of text and number of characters exceeds 80, then the line snaps and text is not appended to rest of the block. I want to find a way such that line does not wrap around in visual mode,but when I am done with appending text, lines should automatically wrap after 80 characters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit**: I initially misunderstood this to be a problem with *pasting*; actually, you mean *appending* from visual mode. The following mapping should handle that, by temporarily resetting `'formatoptions'` until you're done inserting:

```
:xnoremap A <Esc>:let save_fo = &fo<Bar>setl fo=<Bar>augroup TempInsert<Bar>augroup END<Bar>autocmd! TempInsert InsertLeave * let &fo = save_fo<Bar>autocmd! TempInsert<CR>gvA
```

---

I only see this effect with auto-formatting, i.e. `:set formatoptions+=a`.

If you don't want this when pasting, you could override the command, or provide a special alternative, like this:

```
:nnoremap <Leader>p :let save_fo = &fo<Bar>setl fo-=a<Bar>execute 'normal! "' . v:register . 'p'<Bar>let &fo = save_fo<CR>
```

Comment: I checked my formatoptions. It is set as 'tcroql'. Sorry if my question was not clear enough. I have no issues with auto-formatting. I would just like it to be "paused" when I am using visual mode, and resume after I exit it.

Comment: Interesting, I don't see wrapping under such circumstances. Does my solution work when you do `:setl fo-=c fo-=t` instead of `:setl fo-=a`? You could also `:set paste` ... `:set nopaste` instead.

Comment: I think that what he is doing is pressing `A` in a visual block. I see the same behavior on my side. It should be possible to remap `A` in such conditions to save and reset `tw`, as you did with `fo`.

Comment: @Vitor: Thanks, I think I really misunderstood. Yes, such remap is possible, if somewhat more complex. I've added that.